# jQuery Full Calendar not displaying events from url, but also no errors

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to use the [jQuery Full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plugin, with the JSON url option, but it is not throwing any errors, but events are also not displaying. I cannot figure out what the issue could be.

**Full Calendar Call:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({                                                                                           
    aspectRatio: 1.3,                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',                                                                                          
    slotMinutes: 15,                                                                                                    
    editable: true,                                                                                                     
    allDaySlot:false,                                                                                                   
    events: '/appt/appointments/json_event_source'                                                                                                                 
});
```

**Example Response From URL**

```
[
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Adrian Adams",
    "start": "1346339700",
    "end": "1346340600"
   },
   {
     "id": "3",
     "title": null,
     "start": "1346166000",
     "end": "1346169600"
   },
   {
     "id": "4",
     "title": "asdfEditeda asdf",
     "start": "1346335200",
     "end": "1346335200"
   },
   {
     "id": "5",
     "title": "asdfEditeda asdf",
     "start": "1346335200",
     "end": "1346335200"
   },
   {
     "id": "6",
     "title": "asdfEditeda asdf",
     "start": "1346335200",
     "end": "1346339700"
   }
]
```

Comment: What dateFormat is that? Date in milliseconds? I don't think FullCalendar recognizes that - and `start` is a required field for an event object, so I think it fails to render.

Comment: @ganeshk it's a unix timestamp, which the docs say it should accept. also I don't understand the second part of your comment, each event object does have a 'start' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The `title` attribute in the event object is a required and can't be `null` (as in your 2nd event). I changed that to an empty string and the calendar rendered fine.

Take a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/M8RRR/

You might want to add a validation to your server-side code to not return objects with no titles.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I tried removing that event, still not rendering for some reason.  However the server validation is a good point, I'll make sure to account for that.

Comment: Hmm - I tried the exact response string you posted above in the fiddle - changing null to "" worked perfectly for me!